# How to change the accessibility focus programatically?

Tags: flutter, accessibility, focus, talkback, setfocus

In the **Home Page** I have a button called `Select Language`. When the button is clicked it will navigate to the new page where we can select the language.

Now what I want to achieve is when I navigate to the language selection page The talkback focus should be the `AppBar() title`.But it always goes to the back button in the `AppBar()`. So I used the `Focus()` Widget to programatically change the focus to the AppBar title.After warping the `Text()` widget with the `Focus()` widget, The talkback focus was always in the title but only in the **debug build**. In the **release build** the talkback focus was in the back button and rarely in the title.

From the last two days of digging what I found is the accessibility focus and input focus are two different things. We can't change the accessibility focus with the `FocusNode()`. Well in some cases it did change.

These are some of the forms I referred

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94523

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/107069

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59594

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/97747 - still open

With the latest update in the flutter is there anyway to change the accessibility focus programatically?

**Home Page Code:**

```
import 'package:device_info/language_selection.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
            context,
            CupertinoPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const LanguagePage(),
            ),
          ),
          child: const Text(
            "Select Language",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Language Selection Page:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LanguagePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LanguagePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<LanguagePage> createState() => _LanguagePageState();
}

class _LanguagePageState extends State<LanguagePage> {
  FocusNode languageFoucsNode = FocusNode();
  String language = "";
  List<String> languageList = [
    "Tamil",
    "Malayalam",
    "Telugu",
    "English",
    "Kanadam",
    "Hindi"
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        excludeHeaderSemantics: true,
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        title: Focus(
          autofocus: true,
          focusNode: languageFoucsNode,
          child: Text(
            language.isNotEmpty ? language : "Please Select a Language",
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: languageList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                language = languageList[index];
              });
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Text(
              languageList[index],
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Puriyala, enna pannanum?

Comment: @AlexSunderSingh When I go to the language selection page the Talkback focus should be in the appbar title. but it will always goes to the back button in the release build. I have also edited the question see if it's clear and understandable now.